# How to get previous year from Current date/sysdate amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I get data from the Sales Cycle table for dates from 202308 as I used field `start date > Sysdate`. If I want to get everything from `202201` - Sales Cycle Name,
How to Achieve that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I Am new to amazon redshift.

Below is the data I have:

3rd , 4th and 5th row is what I am looking for as output, I want to get everything from `202201`. I used `Start date > Sysdate` where it picked `202308` cycle which is the current cycle. I want all the cycles from `202201`. How to achieve that???

```
10149   1981    2023-07-08  2023-08-04  202308  1
10150   1982    2023-08-05  2023-09-01  202309  2
10151   1983    2023-09-02  2023-09-29  202310  3
10152   1984    2023-09-30  2023-10-27  202311  4
10153   1985    2023-10-28  2023-11-24  202312  5
10154   1986    2023-11-25  2023-12-22  202313  6
```

Comment: `SYSDATE` returns the current date and time in the current session time zone (UTC by default). So if you need data for StartDate greater than `2022-01` you cannot use the `SYSDATE` function either specify the condition as `STARTDATE > '2022-01-01'` or `STARTDATE > '2022-01'`

Comment: I want to do it dynamically? Not to hardcode the year. Need to do trunc of Year minus one. How should i do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE SalesCycle 
(
    ID  INT,
    Number  INT,
    Start_Date  DATE,
    End_Date    DATE,
    Period  INT,
    Count   INT
);

INSERT INTO SalesCycle (ID, Number, Start_Date, End_Date, Period, Count) VALUES ('10149', '1981', '2023-07-08', '2023-08-04', '202308', '1');
INSERT INTO SalesCycle (ID, Number, Start_Date, End_Date, Period, Count) VALUES ('10150', '1982', '2023-08-05', '2023-09-01', '202309', '2');
INSERT INTO SalesCycle (ID, Number, Start_Date, End_Date, Period, Count) VALUES ('10151', '1983', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-29', '202310', '3');
INSERT INTO SalesCycle (ID, Number, Start_Date, End_Date, Period, Count) VALUES ('10152', '1984', '2023-09-30', '2023-10-27', '202311', '4');
INSERT INTO SalesCycle (ID, Number, Start_Date, End_Date, Period, Count) VALUES ('10153', '1985', '2023-10-28', '2023-11-24', '202312', '5');
INSERT INTO SalesCycle (ID, Number, Start_Date, End_Date, Period, Count) VALUES ('10154', '1986', '2023-11-25', '2023-12-22', '202313', '6');
```

**Option 1 :** If you want to fetch the data for an year from current time then you can use `DATEADD(YEAR,-1,SYSDATE)` this function is used to subtract an year from the current date

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,-1,SYSDATE) AS CLAUSE,* FROM 
SALESCYCLE 
WHERE START_DATE > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,SYSDATE);
```

**Option 2 :** If you want to fetch the data from the last year first month then you would need to apply this `CONCAT(DATE_PART(YEAR, SYSDATE)-1 , '-01')`

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_PART(YEAR, SYSDATE)-1 , '-01') AS CLAUSE,SYSDATE,* FROM 
SALESCYCLE
WHERE START_DATE > CONCAT(DATE_PART(YEAR, SYSDATE)-1, '-01');
```

You can run the below query and see how you would like to fetch the data and use the right filter option

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,-1,SYSDATE), SYSDATE, CONCAT(DATE_PART(YEAR, SYSDATE)-1 , '-01');
```

| date_add | timestamp | concat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-30 14:49:44.318 | 2023-08-30 14:49:44.318 | 2022-01 |